# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered & FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am attempting to build an app using `Expo` and `Firebase`. However, I am reciving the following errors:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
> - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

> Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
> * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

While similar questions regarding this error have been posted, the difference lies that the app was properly running without the error and no changes have been made outside of the screens since. However, I have tried the solutions provided in similar questions, such as deleting the node_modules and downloading them again.

I would really appreciate any insight into how such an issue can arise when editing the screen, as Metro was working properly before. Thank you so much!

Edit: This is the firebase Init Code

```js
    const firebaseConfig = {
       // removed secret keys
    };

    // check if firebase init
    let app;
    if (!firebase.apps.length){
      app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    } else {
      app = firebase.app();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code that initializes Firebase?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Added!

Comment: Have you recently upgraded to version 9 from version 8 perhaps?

Comment: @Phobos I did not perform any version changes between the app working and the error showing up